# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" found in ---> <Blogpage> at src/views/blogPage/blogpage.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, null

I'm trying my hands on Vue, and any exhaustive explanation will be well welcome. I'm trying to display info coming from News API after clicking but I keep getting this error of null

this is the template code:

```
<div class="popular-card my-4" v-if="popular.length" ref="displayPopular">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 d-flex mt-4" v-for="populars in popular" :key="populars.id">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 100%; height: 38em">
                      <img style=" height:250px; width: 100%" :src='populars.urlToImage' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"> {{populars.title}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"> {{populars.content | shortenString}} </p>
                        <p class="mt-5"> {{populars.author}} </p>
                        <p class=" d-flex align-self-end"> {{populars.publishedAt | dateConvert}}, 3min read</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div class="ml-auto mt-4"><h6  class="popular-article" @click="getAllarticlesOnThisCategory" ref="popularArticle">SEE ALL POPULAR ARTICLE</h6></div>
            </div>
```

this is the method:

and in my data object, popular is set to an empty array:[]

```
getAllarticlesOnThisCategory () {
      console.log('hey')
      // this.spin = true
      this.$http.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&apiKey=3d65f891e67841f3b2ca700bb*****`)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.popular = data.articles.slice(5)
          console.log(this.popular[2].description)
        })
      if (!this.popularDisplay) {
        this.popularDisplay = true
        this.$refs.popularArticle.innerText = 'SEE LESS ARTICLE'
      } else {
        this.popularDisplay = false
        this.$refs.popularArticle.innerText = 'SEE POPULAR ARTICLE'
      }
      this.spin = false
    }
```

Comment: Post the code where you set `popular` to empty array. You could check for null before accessing the length property in `v-if`.

Comment: ```data () {
    return {
      headline: [],
      counter: 0,
      popular: [],
      popularDisplay: false,
      spin: false
      // headlineStories: null
    }```

Comment: I tried wrting ```v-if="popular.length && !null"``` but didn't still work

Comment: I meant like this: `v-if="popular !== null && pouplar.length"`

Comment: Seeing as `popular` in null, the problem probably lies in `data.articles.slice(5)`

Comment: i've tried to remove the slice but still the same error; also if i try to console part of the returned data, i get a valid JSON returned in my console, but it doesn't just render on the html